# How to install sopcast-player?

Tags: software-installation, sopcast

All the ppa's I used are for natty or older. How can I install sopcast in oneiric? I prefer through a ppa if it exists.

Should I try the ppa for natty? Will it work? I mean the ppa from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/sopcast)

Usually I install it from Ubuntu tweak. But now Ubuntu tweak is in alpha for oneiric, with a new interface. I couldn't find it there, or any other software. Explain that?

Comment: Also you can try TV Maxe is to similar Sopcast, here is [the link](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-sopcast-player-in-ubuntu-1110.html). Here you will find info about "INSTALL SOPCAST PLAYER IN UBUNTU 11.10 ONEIRIC OCELOT". Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*updated - [PPA has been updated](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/sopcast) with oneiric support - no longer need to edit software sources with natty repo*

[image]

**to install**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/sopcast
```

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sopcast-player
```

Note - see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sopcast-player/+bug/875793) for 64bit workaround if required.

The start sopcast:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. worked. one comment though, i had to disable the ppa, untick it, before editting. if not the edit would not take effect. thanks