# Problems with sopcast

Tags: sopcast

I have a problem with sopcast-player, I have installed it in the computer as in this question is described [How to install sopcast-player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69701/how-to-install-sopcast-player). All correct, its installed in my computer, but when i want to start this program, i can't, I make click on the aplication but it doesn't start.

Comment: Can you try to open a console and type sopcast-player there?. Are there any messages?.

Comment: Do you have a 64bits system?. Have you read the workaround for 64 bits in the question that you quote?.

Comment: I type sopcast-player in a console and this is what appears:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/sopcast-player.py", line 36, in <module>
    from VLCWidget import VLCWidget
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/VLCWidget.py", line 32, in <module>
    import vlc_1_0_x
ImportError: No module named vlc_1_0_x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because there is a missing library.

As stated on the bug report linked in the question, there is a problem with the 64 bits package. To resolve it, you must open a console and type:

```
cd /usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/
ln -s vlc_1_1_x.py vlc_1_0_x.py
```

The package installs a higher version of the library than the one sopcast calls. With the above command you will make a link, so that sopcast call the 1.1 version when it asks for the 1.0. This is a quite ugly workaround, but it should work (I can test it).

Comment: Thanks,but I solve it before saw your comment :D it's maybe the same way as i had done but here is what I did: I type in a console " gksu gedit /usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/VLCWidget.py " when a document appears i searched two lines where we can read " vlc_1_0_x " when i had locatd this two lines y change it by " vlc_1_1_x " and that's all, it works perfectlly